# Nilpotence and module of coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Given a transformation $T\in L(V)$, $T$ nilpotent where $V$ is a vector  space of finite dimension, show that $\forall \epsilon >0$, there exists a basis $\mathcal B$ from $V$ such that $[T]_\mathcal B = (a_{ij})$ and $|a_{ij}|<\epsilon$

I have no clue on how to solve it, I tried using the rational form but it led nowhere.

Comment: This isn't true as stated: if $T$ is the identity, then it's the identity in every basis, so it doesn't work with $\varepsilon=1/2$.

Comment: Should we imagine from the title of your question that $T$ is supposed to be nilpotent?

Comment: Sorry my bad, It is indeed nilpotent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, as noted by Crostul, that $T$ is nilpotent.

The first step, which I assume you know, is to find a basis with respect to which the matrix of $T$ is made of Jordan blocks. Let us consider one of these blocks, so there are linearly independent vectors
$$
v_{0}, v_{1}, \dots, v_{k}
$$
such that
$$
T(v_{0}) = v_{1}, 
T(v_{1}) = v_{2}, \dots, T(v_{k-1}) = v_{k}, T(v_{k}) = 0.
$$
Now given any $a > 0$, consider the linearly independent vectors
$$
v_{0}' = v_{0}, v_{1}' = a^{-1} v_{1}, v_{2}' = a^{-2} v_{2}, \dots, v_{k}' = a^{-k} v_{k}, 
$$
and see what is the matrix of the action of $T$ on the $v_{i}'$.  Then choose $0 < a < \min(1, \epsilon)$.

Comment: We were allowed to use the rational form, but as we know the last columm wouldn't be of zeros, i Will look up for its Jordan form, thanks a lot